# if else statement for a large set of conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a List of observations and a table which states a populationsize (small,medium,large) for every species. I want to add the population size to my observations.

List of observations (much longer):

```
observations <- data.frame("species" = c("Rana temporaria","Rana temporaria", "Bufo bufo", "Bufo bufo"),
                           "stage" = c("adult","egg","adult","adult"),
                           "count" = c(20,40,100,35),
                           "population" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

List for population size (much longer):

```
population <- data.frame("species" = c("Rana temporaria","Bufo bufo","Bufo bufo"),
                         "stage" = c("adult","adult", "egg"),
                         "small" = c("1-5","1-5","0-100"),
                         "medium" = c("6-10","6-50", "101-500"),
                         "large" = c(">10",">50",">500"))
```

Is there a better way to get around than by using a if statement for every conditional like:

```
if(observations$species[1]=="Rana temporaria" & 
   observations$stage[1] == "adult" & 
   observations$count[1] >= 6 & 
   observations$count[1] >= 10) {
  observations$population[1] = "medium"
  }
```

Comment: [Tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) your population data frame, convert your range limits to numeric and split them into `max` and `min` columns and then `join` `observations` and `population`, filtering to obtain the required allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to "tidy"  the `population` data frame, so that max and min are separate columns, ideally from the beginning, or with `pivot_longer` and `separate`. The next step is then a `left_join` and finally filtering of the relevant rows. I modified the data set of the OP, because it did not contain the combination "Rana" with "egg".

```r
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

## slightly changed because Rana - egg combination was missing in population
observations <- data.frame("species" = c("Rana temporaria","Rana temporaria", 
                                         "Bufo bufo", "Bufo bufo"),
                           "stage" = c("adult","adult","egg","adult"),
                           "count" = c(20,40,100,35),
                           "population" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA))

population <- data.frame("species" = c("Rana temporaria","Bufo bufo","Bufo bufo"),
                         "stage" = c("adult","adult", "egg"),
                         "small" = c("1-5","1-5","0-100"),
                         "medium" = c("6-10","6-50", "101-500"),
                         "large" = c(">10",">50",">500"))

pop_tidy <- population |>
  pivot_longer(c("small","medium","large"), names_to="size") |>
  separate(value, into = c("min", "max"), sep = "-", fill = "right") |>
  mutate(min = as.numeric(sub(">", "", min)), 
         max = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(max), 1000, max)))

left_join(observations, pop_tidy, by=c("species", "stage")) |>
  filter(min <= count, count <= max)
#>           species stage count population   size min  max
#> 1 Rana temporaria adult    20         NA  large  10 1000
#> 2 Rana temporaria adult    40         NA  large  10 1000
#> 3       Bufo bufo   egg   100         NA  small   0  100
#> 4       Bufo bufo adult    35         NA medium   6   50
```

**Or as a single pipeline:**

```r
population |>
  pivot_longer(c("small","medium","large"), names_to="size") |>
  separate(value, into = c("min", "max"), sep = "-", fill = "right") |>
  mutate(min = as.numeric(sub(">", "", min)), 
         max = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(max), 1000, max))) |>
  right_join(observations, by = c("species", "stage")) |>
  filter(min <= count, count <= max)
```

A disadvantage of this approach is that the intermediate data frame after `left_join` replicates the rows according to the number of size classes. It would be great if another solution can avoid this.

Comment: The first version had still 2 bugs that are now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

this is a `tidyverse` solution using tidyr, purrr, and dplyr:

```
### Loading library
library(tidyverse)

### Tidying up the population table
population <- cbind(population, 
                    c("small", "medium", "large") %>%
                      map(
                        function(x) 
                          population %>% 
                          select(x) %>% 
                          separate(x, into = paste0(x, c("_lower", "_higher")), convert = TRUE)
                      ) %>%
                      bind_cols()
)

### Merging the population and observation tables, and defining a new "type" variable
df <- observations %>% 
  left_join(population, by = c("species", "stage")) %>% 
  mutate(type = case_when(count < small_higher ~ "small",
                          count > large_higher ~ "large",
                          count > small_higher & count < medium_higher ~ "medium")) %>%
  select(species, stage, count, type)
```

The output:

```
> df
          species stage count   type
1 Rana temporaria adult    20  large
2 Rana temporaria   egg    40   <NA>
3       Bufo bufo adult   100  large
4       Bufo bufo adult    35 medium
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first look for equivalency in both `species` and `stage` columns to create a `rmtch` column, then use it in an `mapply` to subset the levels vector.

```
observations$rmtch <- t(apply(observations[1:2], 1, \(x) {
  r <- x[1] == population$species & x[2] == population$stage
  if (!any(r)) rep.int(NA, length(r)) else r
})) |> max.col()

observations$population <- mapply(\(x, y) {
  c("small", "medium", "large")[1 + sum(x > as.numeric(gsub('.*-', '', population[y, 3:4])))]
}, observations$count, observations$rmtch)

observations[-5]
#           species stage count population
# 1 Rana temporaria adult    20      large
# 2 Rana temporaria   egg    40       <NA>
# 3       Bufo bufo adult   100      large
# 4       Bufo bufo adult    35     medium
```

---

*Data:*

```
observations <- structure(list(species = c("Rana temporaria", "Rana temporaria", 
"Bufo bufo", "Bufo bufo"), stage = c("adult", "egg", "adult", 
"adult"), count = c(20, 40, 100, 35), population = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

population <- structure(list(species = c("Rana temporaria", "Bufo bufo", "Bufo bufo"
), stage = c("adult", "adult", "egg"), small = c("1-5", "1-5", 
"0-100"), medium = c("6-10", "6-50", "101-500"), large = c(">10", 
">50", ">500")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```